# Cannot access disposed object on Socket Close

Tags: c#

My sample listening server works but the only problem is when I execute `StopListening()`, I get an exception saying "Cannot access a disposed object".

```
Socket sListener;
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
Socket handler;

public Server()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartListening();
}

private void StartListening()
{
    try
    {
        sListener = null;
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
        IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
        ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 4510);
        sListener = new Socket(
            ipAddr.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp
            );
        sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);

        sListener.Listen(10);
        Status = (int)ServerStatus.Started;

        AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
        sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);
    }
    catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
}

public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket listener = null;
    Socket handler = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        handler.NoDelay = false;

        object[] obj = new object[2];
        obj[0] = buffer;
        obj[1] = handler;

        handler.BeginReceive(
            buffer,
            0,
            buffer.Length,
            SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
            obj
            );

        AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
        listener.BeginAccept(aCallback, listener);
    }
    catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
}

public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        object[] obj = new object[2];
        obj = (object[])ar.AsyncState;

        byte[] buffer = (byte[])obj[0];

        handler = (Socket)obj[1];

        string content = string.Empty;
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            content += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0,
                bytesRead);

            // If message contains "<EOL>", finish receiving
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOL>") > -1)
            {
                // Convert byte array to string
                string str = content.Substring(0, content.LastIndexOf("<EOL>"));
            }
            else
            {
                // Continues to asynchronously receive data
                byte[] buffernew = new byte[1024];
                obj[0] = buffernew;
                obj[1] = handler;
                handler.BeginReceive(buffernew, 0, buffernew.Length,
                    SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), obj);
            }

            string content_ = content.Replace("<EOL>", "");
            var contents = content_.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToArray();
            Interpret(contents);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
}

//When I press the "Stop Server" button, this will execute so the server will stop listening for new connections.
private void StopListening()
{
    sListener.Close();
}
```

EDIT:
Added the receivedcallback and the buttons for Start and Stop Listening

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartListening();
}

private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StopListening();
}
```

Comment: Are you using StopListening on the same object ?

Comment: Where is the code showing your functions being called?

Comment: It is a normal kind of mishap when you have a pending BeginReceive() and you jerk the floor mat with Close().  You forgot to post the ReceiveCallback() method, it needs try/catch to catch the ObjectDisposeException.  Do nothing, don't call BeginReceive again and just get out of town since the socket is dead.

Comment: Thanks! I left the catch empty on ReceiveCallback() and it works now.